# 25 books - permutation question

Tags: permutations, combinations

Imagine 25 books, 5 groups of books (e.g. maths, biology, history, geography, philosophy...) and all groups has 5 seperate colors of books (black, blue, yellow, red, green). So there are 5 blue books including one from each group.

So the question is, how many possible ways to sort these books, so there are no same group of books next to each other and there are no same color of books next to each other?

I hope I could explain. Thanks in advance,
Koray

Comment: Did you do inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: I tried, but I got stuck since excluding one set (same group or same color) makes it more complex to exclude another one, and I could not figure out how to find the intersection of these two sets.

Comment: Yes, I tried the condition sets $C_i$ which means that $i, i +1$ violates the condition. This is the sum of those with same colour and same group (as these are exclusive), so these by themselves are easy to count. The combinations (i.e. intersections) get a bit tricky indeed. But what else is there...